# Get file date on FTP download

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ftp

I'm using some sample code from Apple: "[SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html)", to make connection with a ftp server.
I already have get and put working, and I'm using:

`_fileSize = [[self.networkStream propertyForKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPResourceSize] integerValue];`

to get the file size before the download starts.

And I would like to know if there is some similar way of getting the modification date of the file (in sever), just to be able to compare him, to know if I make upload or download.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CFFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CFFTPSample/Listings/CFFTPSample_c.html).  It shows how to use `CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing()` to get a `CFDateRef` for when files in the directory were modified.  Unfortunately it's a fairly arduous procedure, but there doesn't seem to be an easy-to-use FTP library available for the iPhone.